# Can you encrypt data in AWS services without using Key Management Service (KMS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, hsm

I would like to encrypt data in a few Amazons services (mainly RDS) with keys stored in an HSM locally.

If you were to do this normally with AWS you would bring your key into the Customer Managed Key Store and use its ARN when encrypting the service.

I am trying to skip this step and host my own keys, providing them directly to the service without storing them on AWS. I know you can do this with an S3 bucket which is documented here '[Use Your own Encryption Keys with S3’s Server-Side Encryption](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-encryption-with-your-keys/)' but I cannot find out how to do this with other services.

Comment: good question, I will try to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS services that support encryption integrate with KMS. So the short answer is, **no**, you have to use KMS, even when working with your own imported keys (with the exception of S3 that you've already noted).

This is a good thing, KMS is a fully managed service that automatically handles availability, scalability, security, and hardware maintenance for the underlying Key Management Infrastructure (KMI). It also works in concert with AWS CloudTrail to provide you with detailed auditing information. When you add this all up, you get greater control over the lifecycle and durability of your keys. See the list of services that integrate with KMS here:
https://aws.amazon.com/kms/features/#AWS_Service_Integration

If you have to meet specific compliance requirements, KMS integrates with **AWS CloudHSM** through the *KMS custom key store feature*.

S3 and RDS are different types of services and encrypt different things, differently.

With **S3** REST API, it makes sense that you can optionally send your self-managed encryption key on each request, whether for writing or reading an object. You're ultimately responsible for these keys, if you lost them, you lost your data.

More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

In **RDS**, encryption is used differently. When encryption is enabled for an RDS instance, the data that is encrypted at rest includes the **underlying storage** for DB instances, its automated backups, read replicas, and snapshots. It's not a simple S3 PUT or GET.

You may want to take a look at Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) support for Oracle and SQL Server which offers encryption at the database file level, performing real-time I/O encryption and decryption of the data and log files (regardless of underlying storage).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-cloudhsm-is-now-integrated-with-amazon-rds-for-oracle-and-provides-enhanced-management-tools/